# Matplotlib - 3D surface plot disappears when cmap colors are specified

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a script that generates 3D plots from an initial set of x/y values that are not a mesh grid. The script runs well and converts the data into a mesh grid and plots it fine but when I specify a cmap color the plot disappears. Why would this happen?

code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = []
y = []
rlim = -4
llim = 4
increment = np.absolute((llim-rlim)*5)
linespace = np.array(np.linspace(rlim,llim,increment, endpoint = False))

for val in linespace:
    for val1 in linespace:
        x.append(val)
        y.append(val1)

x = np.array(x) 
y = np.array(y) 
z = np.array(np.sin(np.sqrt(np.power(x,2)+np.power(y,2)))/np.sqrt(np.power(x,2)+np.power(y,2)))

rows = len(np.unique(x[~pd.isnull(x)]))
array_size = len(x)
columns = int(array_size/rows)

X = np.reshape(x, (rows, columns))
Y = np.reshape(y, (rows, columns))
Z = np.reshape(z, (rows, columns))

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                 cmap = 'Blues', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

This yields[image]

However if all I do is delete the cmap entry in ax.plot_surface I ge the following:

[image]

Why simply adding a cmap delete the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib is having a hard time scaling your colormap with `NaN`s in the `Z` matrix. I didn't look too close at your function, but it seems like you will get a `NaN` at the origin `(0,0)`, and it looks like `1` is a reasonable replacement. Therefore, right after `Z = np.reshape(z, (rows, columns))` I added `Z[np.isnan(Z)] = 1.`, resulting in the following pretty graph:
[image]